# Double line loop search in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I am using Python 3 and I need to extract data from a file. An example of the data is below:

```
ENERGY_BOUNDS 
  1.964033E+07  1.733253E+07  1.491825E+07  1.384031E+07  1.161834E+07  1.000000E+07  8.187308E+06  6.703200E+06
  6.065307E+06  5.488116E+06  4.493290E+06  3.678794E+06  3.011942E+06  2.465970E+06  2.231302E+06  2.018965E+06
GAMMA_INTERFACE
     0
EIGENVALUE 
  1.219034E+00
N,2N
  1.191994E+00  1.535081E+00  1.543891E+00  1.413861E+00  1.181815E+00  6.174152E-01  1.302440E-02  0.000000E+00
  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00
  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00
MACRO      1
SIGABS 
 -3.826074E-03 -3.707513E-04  2.610351E-03  6.961084E-03  7.832982E-03  7.512567E-03  1.018417E-02  1.276596E-02
  9.148128E-03  8.828235E-03  8.527789E-03  7.514346E-03  7.544248E-03  7.801064E-03  7.724884E-03  7.047571E-03
  5.280749E-03  3.999751E-03  3.821688E-03  3.748186E-03  3.712753E-03  3.591795E-03  3.390300E-03  3.180354E-03
SIGTRAN 
  7.513455E-02  8.061355E-02  8.377954E-02  8.787775E-02  9.114071E-02  9.170817E-02  9.440786E-02  9.535947E-02
  1.010975E-01  1.035364E-01  1.160553E-01  1.290131E-01  1.197249E-01  1.151962E-01  1.298934E-01  1.375417E-01
  1.428861E-01  1.715100E-01  1.627465E-01  2.026621E-01  2.007540E-01  1.644982E-01  1.781501E-01  1.624188E-01
```

The process needs to be:

Search the file line by line until the starting keyword (MACRO in this case) is found.

After this, continue searching line by line until the specific identifier is found.

Read each value in the lines after the identifier into an array or list.

Stop reading once another identifier is found.

So far this is what I have. The code works fine if the identifier is the first value after MACRO (e.g. if it is SIGABS) but not for any others (e.g. SIGTRAN). My results file has maybe 50 different identifiers in it so I need the code to be able to pick out one at a time.

```
def read_data_from_file_macro(file_name, start_macro, identifier):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as read_obj:
        list_of_results = []
        # Read all lines in the file one by one
        for line in read_obj:
            # For each line, check if line contains the string
            if start_macro in line:
            # If MACRO is found, start looking for the identifier read the next line
                nextValue = next(read_obj)
                if identifier in nextValue:
                # If identifier is found read next line
                    nextValue = next(read_obj)
                    while(not nextValue.strip().isidentifier()): #keep on reading untill next identifier appears 
                        list_of_results.extend(nextValue.split())
                        nextValue = next(read_obj)
                        # Convert to float
                        for i in range(0, len(list_of_results)): 
                                list_of_results[i] = float(list_of_results[i])
    return(list_of_results)
```

Comment: what is the integer that represents '-3.826074E-03'?

Comment: ...d'oh. Have taken that bit out, thank you!

Comment: Can you explain this line?    `while(not nextValue.strip().isidentifier()):`    How isidentifier() is defined?

Comment: iterate line of file until MAKRO found, set a boolean. iterate further lines until your keyword is found, set another boolean.  while line starts with a space, read lines into list. If line does not start with a space, reset both bools to false and process list. All your "data" is indented by 1 space ... keywords: are not.

Comment: isidentifier() checks whether the next value is a valid identifier - any letter, number, or underscore but it can't start with a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. It handles you file as text, separates the part that is included between your start_identifier and end_identifier and with some work it returns a list of floats that is finally extended in your list_of_results (which must preexist before the function is called, so you must firstly create it manually). You can run for any pair of identifiers. Let me know how it works

```
def read_data_from_file_macro(file_name, start_identifier, end_identifier):
    with open(file_name) as f:
    t=f.read()
    t=t[t.find('MACRO'):]
    t=t[t.find(start_identifier)+len(start_identifier):t.find(end_identifier)]
    t=t.replace('\n', '').split()
    t=[float(i) for i in t if not i.isidentifier()]
    list_of_results.extend(t)
```